# jQuery erratic triggering on simple animation

Tags: jquery

Hi 
I have an image around 150px wide by 300px deep. When I roll over  it I want a little image to pop up on top. When I roll off the bigger image I want the smaller one to disappear.

It all works, except that if you mouseover the triggering image where the new image pops up then it appears to go into some kind of loop or behave erratically as you move themouse. I have tried hover and mouseover/out. I expect it is triggering rolloff/rollon events as the mouse is moved.

You can see this a [www.ypfservice.net](http://www.ypfservice.net)

Thanks in advance

E

here's my jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var numberLinks = $('a.panelImage').length;

    for (var j = 0; j < numberLinks; j++) {

        var currentLink = $('a.panelImage').eq(j);

        //    var currentLink = $('a.panelImage:eq('+j+')');                  
        $('<div class="fred"></div>').insertAfter(currentLink);

        var gtr = currentLink.position().left + 'px';

        $(currentLink).next().css({ // ie div.fred
            'position': 'absolute',
            'background-position': '0 0',
            'top': '100px',
            'left': gtr,
            'display': 'none',
            'width': '5px',
            'height': '5px',
            'overflow': 'hidden',
            'backgroundImage': 'url(http://www.ypfservice.net/templates/ypftemplate/images/foyerPreview.jpg)',
        });

    }


    $('a.panelImage img').mouseover(function () {
        $(this).parent().next().stop().animate({
            height: '138px',
            width: '184px'
        }, 500)
    }).mouseout(function () {
        $(this).parent().next().stop().animate({
            'width': '0px',
            'height': '0px'
        }, 500);
    }); //end function

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handle the mouseover/mouseout events for the parent element instead:

```
$('a.panelImage').parent().mouseover(function () {
    $(this).find(".panelImage").next().stop().animate({
        height: '138px',
        width: '184px'
    }, 500)
}).mouseout(function () {
    $(this).find(".panelImage").next().stop().animate({
        'width': '0px',
        'height': '0px'
    }, 500);
}); //end function
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply - this made perfect sense and worked well.

Comment: well, it does work great in FF and IE. But nothing happens at all in Opera, Chrome or Safari (pc). Any ideas why??? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The smaller image is part of the same selector of the bigger image. As you mouse out of the big image and mouse over the smaller one, you trigger both the out and over events.

Try giving the bigger image an ID, and using that.

Comment: Thanks for the tip - above answer worked straight away, so am going to stick with that one. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Use mouseenter and mouseleave instead. jQuery fires a mouseout when you touch your animated element. That won't happen with mouseenter/mouseleave.

Comment: thanks -have researched the mouseenter/leave. When I  just replaced mouseover/out this didn't work. I could see that they probably would, but as yet I don't really get "binding" which I think I have to use.